# group_by (dplyr, R) not working with unit ID and time--aggregating by unit ID only

Tags: r, dplyr, time, panel-data

I have two panel data sets that are mergeable. However, I have to create bins of time as both data sets are highly imbalanced and have highly variable measurement occasions.

One approach is the following:

```
    panel_df1_monthly <- panel_df1 %>%
    mutate(TimeMetric_Monthly = floor_date(TimeVariable, unit = "month")) %>%
    group_by(ID, TimeMetric_Monthly) %>%
    summarize(Monthly_Avg_Value1 = mean(Value1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
    panel_df2_monthly <- panel_df2 %>%
    mutate(TimeMetric_Monthly = floor_date(TimeVariable, unit = "month")) %>%
    group_by(ID, TimeMetric_Monthly) %>%
    summarize(Monthly_Avg_Value2 = mean(Value2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, regardless of the time metric chosen (e.g., month, quarter), the aggregated statistic is the same. The value should vary depending on the time metric and the new data sets (e.g., panel_df1_monthly, panel_df1_quarterly) should look different, with a column for the new time metric and another column with it's corresponding value for another variable. Here, all the new panel datasets look alike.

I have also tried other approaches, but these do not produce harmonizable panel datasets the new time metrics do not align across them.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Make `cols <- c("ID", "TimeVariable", "Value1")` and please edit the question with the output of `dput(df[cols])`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df[cols], 20))`.

Comment: Is the summarization happening by group? Sometimes people encounter unexpected behavior with grouped data sets because they have loaded the `plyr` package, which has a `summarize` function which does not see groupings.

Comment: I don't know if this is about the summarization or the visualization. If you say the facets do not align, then it could be either. Please add sample data, plotting code, an image, and explain what is wrong about the image. Perhaps it's not about the plot, but since you mentioned it I think it's worth taking a look at it. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions about reproducibility, please.)